# TS: How to define return typing of reusable chained methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, method-chaining

I have the following code:

```
const mixed = {
  validations: [] as any[],
  formattings: [] as any[],
  exceptions: [] as any[],
  required(message?: string) {
    this.validations.push({
      name: 'required',
      message: message || config.messages.mixed.required,
      test: (value: string) => {
        return value && value.trim() ? true : false
      },
    })

    return this
  },
  // other methods that will be reusable
}

const string = () => ({
  ...mixed,
  maxWords(maxWords: number, message?: string) {
    type Params = { maxWords: number }

    this.validations.push({
      name: 'maxWords',
      params: { maxWords },
      message: message || config.messages.string.maxWords,
      test: (value: string, { maxWords }: Params) => {
        const wordCount = value.trim().split(' ').length

        return wordCount <= maxWords
      },
    })

    return this
  },

  trim() {
    this.formattings.push({
      name: 'trim',
      format: (value: string) => {
        return value.trim()
      },
    })

    return this
  },
})

const number = () => ({
  ...mixed,
  positive(message?: string) {
    this.validations.push({
      name: 'positive',
      message: message || config.messages.string.maxWords,
      test: (value: string) => {
        // make a validation
      },
    })

    return this
  },
})

const schema = {
  string() {
    return string()
  },
  number() {
    return number()
  },
  // file, date, etc..
}

const form = {
  name: schema.string().required().trim().maxWords(3),
  age: schema.number().required().positive(),
}
```

Everything works perfectly in execution, the problem is that I am trying to build a form validation library and I need intellisense working on all methods.

[here's the problem](https://i.ibb.co/jG6MNx8/Captura-de-Tela-2021-05-19-a-s-00-24-32.png)

Here's [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDbACZzMAexGQG8AoZZEOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwuTqabnYbNWHLgAc4UWkwD8jAEoQEBKNgA8LNiHYAaZHBABPAHxdILRgAoAbpgCug-Qd24wcWXsMBKZAF4jyACMCAgwIfTIAXzIyUEhYRBQAMWUaPHwtUi5qOkYNEUoYFLxLGwx7RkdvPw8DSOjY6HgkZABRAA8kUXwiTMpswTytLhc3eUVlNUGdGpMosiUQFmQFmGB2CsNfXuQMAgRMQQByLoBaACE5Q+0uHj4BJkZD4BpRZUhsZBgoAhoPAjAABbQT7AUJXLgAeghADpYXV5kQljRgG0IB8fNtSjg8IRFowANoAXT0TDQmGx3RAROuBSKYHS7AeyCJJOQySgqXpHGpXAgHQgXVxTJZcFJ7U6lJ5lCgEAAjrZgDLsBZbvwIO4pt5yJRKIDgExoViXELoaJbEwARZtTq+rQjjL5Yq0eCbZRVQJGO6UAAfb3LIirdjQr0G5Go7DQh0KpU011mMAlOwDYRaKr+a2u5AysC2KDEUr2ZAAMiLyALEGhwhoFm80mQrELjHgGCYEC4NoiscoEU80Rt2dzxD1TC4nchEOQ-yBUG4EEBBGwpMBeGQAHdQRhAigZea4AFQvCFksplsa75-FauLDgyi0bHUm0AOoTJgquBPl+MEC2GgBaC6L0NRTdgtXbesDFEFAAAUJCkLYSG4d9nxUJlv1-YE5htYdDXJY1EVNc1LQzHV+keB9kMXF1XXESQaCZBDyJfZAx0zL1PQgXg1WQX1-RAQNgw4u4OOhKZgyQl8ux1eNEzKZNNGmBjxJQ5jGBg2imDTbZMyPMA1wmABhAhbHALZy0rNhq08ETRCwMALEOZBDis0ItEBPtMyzOdBz0lRDOM3TVAxRiULA7tJJ7dzpS8vN6wBfVR2uUwLLPYjsMKDk0g4A0zQtS9M1Ixyqyom10s5GTyiEeTNOI-tovzJNzOeGtQuY8LezAgcYuHBLInanSqB-P8ZwxM9qjy5BrzDO8xAIJhgHwKwIBVQS1SAqqtNi-UcKwPDFgI3KaqoO1HleOaFogYqdTY2dOIEbi-RWNYBNu4TROCxdJN1DiE2Qawk1yYDqpaygoUQgBrFA4DLXCcSIYHPJzLqoHsFqWJ1CKOrqzaRzC3ron6pgECBVJ4K4KYUsxxHiHJ3tcb6QboAp2qqYG9CoGaunkFB1ZQmcPAIF0OcEDhOZ+tK0nbRyZgiYgVIROAmtIzlaM0UVqtFfe18AGZPFjNVchluW0KGxWoydZUrNO+bgEWmtriiIA) so you can test it in real time.

the problem is in the typing of the returns of each function

Comment: You can try `bar<T>(this: T): T` (here - but in general, you will want your validation library use a generic type for the schema)

Comment: @Bergi ssolves the problem of intellisense in the chaining of methods but and creates another problem, now if I try to access `this` within the function itself, I will no longer have intellisense and typescript keeps complaining, [see a example in this image](https://i.ibb.co/ydWqvBX/Captura-de-Tela-2021-05-18-a-s-22-45-27.png)

Comment: You'll want either `foo<T extends …>`, or define your `data` on a `Schema<T>` and make `foo` a method of that. Posting your actual code for the validator, not just a toy example of object literals, would help to give more precise advice.

Comment: @Bergi sorry, my code is a little big, but i put it here for you to view and already be able to make changes in real time [TS Playground](http://encurtador.com.br/FPR12) 
you can see the problem in the last [form const](https://i.ibb.co/DKsVXC9/Captura-de-Tela-2021-05-18-a-s-23-24-24.png)

Comment: @Bergi in case you put your hand on, click on 'shake' to create a new link, and use a shortener to shorten and send me here or just add a reply to my post

Comment: @Bergi 'share'* `foo<T extends …>` extends what?

Comment: That url shortener doesn't work for me. Just [edit] your question to include the code - omit a few of the methods and properties that are not relevant, but keep the structure.

Comment: @Bergi 
I just updated my code

Comment: Oh, it really is object literals. Have you considered using `class`es? But even without, try declaring a proper interface type, do not use that scary `validations: [] as any[]`. Then, if you have an interface type, you can use that.

Comment: @Bergi stack overflow was complaining that there was a lot of code and you said to omit things, so that was one of the things I omitted, but you can check the complete code at ts playground, there you will see that it has defined interfaces

Comment: Oops, it's actually simpler than I thought: just `bar(): this`. No generics needed. See the duplicate :-)

Comment: @Bergi 
`bar(): this` doesn't work for me, [see this image](https://i.ibb.co/ryTQwNT/Captura-de-Tela-2021-05-19-a-s-00-39-33.png)

Comment: Oh I had missed the playground link in the post. Yeah, there are interfaces, but these still use `value: any` as arguments to their `test` and `format` methods. Use generics there, and ensure that `mixed` methods work with `unknown` whereas the `number()` methods use `number` etc

Comment: @Bergi i'm very confused, if not too inconvenient, could you take my code and change it in a way that works? you can just write online here [https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?)

Comment: @Bergi 
it can be using classes, so it has the same structure as mine, as you said, not a toy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `required(message?: string): this` if you declare the method type in an interface or class. Stripped down example:

```
interface Validation<T> {
  message: string
  test: (value: T) => boolean
}

interface FormField<T> {
  validations: Validation<T>[];
  required(message: string): this;
}

const mixed: FormField<unknown> = {
  validations: [],
  required(message) {
    this.validations.push({
      message,
      test(value: string) {
        return value.trim()
      }
    })
    return this
  }
}

interface StringField extends FormField<string> {
  maxWords(maxWords: number, message: string): this;
}
const string = (): StringField => ({
  ...mixed as StringField, // this is a bit ugly, would work better if mixed() was a function or superclass
  maxWords(maxWords, message) {
    this.validations.push({
      message,
      test: value => value.trim().split(' ').length <= maxWords,
    })
    return this
  }
})

interface NumberField extends FormField<number> {
  positive(message: string): this;
}

const number = (): NumberField => ({
  ...mixed as NumberField,
  positive(message) {
    this.validations.push({
      message,
      test: value => value > 0,
    })

    return this
  },
})

const form = {
  name: string().required('missing name').maxWords(3, 'too few words'),
  age: number().required('missing age').positive('must be born already'),
}
```

<sup>([TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDbACZzMAexAB4AVAPmQG8AoZZAWwgGdm4BzCALmWbClDs6ySHx4AKAG6YArt2SkAlMgC8lAEYECGCHBA0AvjRqhIsRCgBiBKA0vAIGbGUq160rLnxFmPdJ7xCEgoAbQBdAG5hKAgARxlgGOxxJlYOeT4BEHZFHjAAC2BmKKMaBB8wRmAADwhsHmtbe0dnGRAAaxACAHcQShVqYQ8cQJ8ecIAaaLiEpJSWNk5lN3oRQuYAOmGvIM2ABxlmfPEV1cYF9Kmz+lEwKVkM-kFl4WvkGLAZKBBkDzkNp4McSKV6rIxnAwgs4fL4-ApFYRGUqmaDwJDIADKT2yzScyAg1UgIGwzGQjTsDicxEyglcwgYcGqAHUbCSUoyWVASTwQDIGOpoBNzmlODwadlcmsiiUyhVeNj2KpkMCeFisuxcdhVJQTsINvqGDU6sg4KS1YJNUKAPRWqWkoom5DqYCVGTsDAATyF3QIMjxPqg7SdEDAZmQwBgVVqyWU3VNjpgbQQ3h+Nl4Mj20AQGFNzHpHNZzHZzMLQtSiwgLzO8M221GIH2h2Op1W5cuoJuLDAPD+KDUvweAIEQMUG2YeywdwA5Mgp6OdNkCshiAMGSWucwrmCoasYd87YjDCCTOBURZkAA5PkCqCa-GEiDE0nkzXEXn86B0+h7AjMF3ASQIHmEVHnVSUaxlWUG0qd8byVFVL2vaA737XV6H1DZDWjE1SSvD9b0pbAtx-P98EA4CKyrVYay2TARhTRsjjQ64204Ldqy7HsHm1AcMDkZBKAABnY5BIWMaEQ1hA96AMKYxKgvhkBgGwGCVFYQDgJgxQVYENhieJEjqcQp0NVhBGQDSmDnTCCw3cQAGYhSnMAtCUiBumQAMSTnLd0h5JCoF0-TZiMkyij-bITU4aySP-ciTMOSoBSdGwfkwGI4GwD0fMMGggA))</sup>

Comment: I will mark your answer as a solution, I would like one last request, I decided to test the structure with `Classes` as you suggested, [this is result](https://cutt.ly/yb0w606), do you have any more advice?

Comment: @YungSilva "*this is the result*" - does it work for you? Notice that you want `schema.string` to return a `new` instance every time, not the `const string`. (If this was actually meant to be a singleton, you wouldn't need/shouldn't use `class`es)

Comment: yeah, my bad, [i am returning a new instance of Class now](https://cutt.ly/Cb0evbj), the final result I need is something like [yup](https://i.ibb.co/mXdv0gj/Captura-de-Tela-2021-05-19-a-s-01-27-20.png)